# std::move before assignment in the same expression

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Consider the following snippet:

```cpp
std::string foo(std::string x) {
    x += "!";
    return x;
}
// ...
std::string y = "Hello";
// ...
y = foo(y);
```

My questions:

- Does the compiler recognize that `y` can be moved when passed to `foo`, since it's going to be assigned into right after that.
- If not, is it valid for me to add `std::move` for passing `y` to `foo`: `y = foo(std::move(y))`? Does it eliminate all copies?

Comment: For the first bullet, most likely not, since the compiler usually can't infer whether or not the copy constructor has any observerable side effects, so omiting the copy could violate the as-if principle. [Copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is only permitted in a handful of cases enumerated in the standard, and this does not look like one of them. For the second, yes that use of move is valid, but there may still be copies performed depending on whether using `+=` causes a reallocation and whether your compiler implements NRVO.

Comment: @Brian reallocation on `+=` - sure, is possible; but for ` y = foo(move(y));` - where can the copy occur? Move into function - process the string (assume reallocation has not happened) - return and directly move-assign into y.

Comment: @alagner AFAIK, the only possible copy is in the last part. Not invoking the copy (or move) constructor when returning a named object by value is an optional (though common) optimization. In theory, you compiler is free to invoke the copy constructor at that point, though in practice all modern compilers should optimize that out.

Comment: On second thought, I may be wrong about whether compilers are allowed to invoke the copy constructor at the return when a move constructor is available. Maybe someone more familiar with the standard can chime in about that. Either way, a smart compiler should optimize it out, so I doubt there's any real concern about a copy being made there.

Comment: @Brian: Recent versions of the standard have fiddled with the rules, but there should be an implicit `std::move` of a function parameter like that.

Comment: @Brian of course, compiler may elide the move or copy operation completely; I agree it's optional. However, the question is about "copy" explicitly and I wanted to point out that move!=nrvo, nor move is copy. And move is required for the second case (as long as move assignment operator for the class exsists - it does for string).

Answer (score 2):

> Does the compiler recognize that `y` can be moved when passed to `foo`,
> since it's going to be assigned into right after that.

No, it is not allowed to do it. `std::move()` is merely a cast, in this case into `std::string&&`. Without the cast, `std::string::string(const std::string&)` constructor signature will be chosen, which is a copy constructor.

> If not, is it
> valid for me to add `std::move` for passing `y` to `foo`: `y =`
> `foo(std::move(y))`? Does it eliminate all copies?

Sure, you can, and it does eliminate all copies. First, argument `y` is moved into parameter `x`. On the return, `x` is moved into `y`.

Comment: An assignment can’t be elided, although `x` could be the parameter for the assignment operator.  (As-if applies, of course.)